# Which are some best sources to learn Algebraic Quantum Field Theory (AQFT)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations

Which are some best sources to learn Algebraic Quantum Field Theory ([AQFT](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AQFT))?

I am a beginner and  I am currently following Haag's Local Quantum Physics and feel like I need some more notes or some extra supplementary book or something like that.

Which are some other best books?

Comment: Perhaps you want something witteny, https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0616

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be sure that you are handling the **second edition** of Haag's book!

I can also suggest H.Araki's book [Mathematical Theory of Quantum Fields](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199566402)
which is a bit more mathematically detailed than Haag's book, but covers a smaller area.

The very recent  [Advances in Algebraic Quantum Field Theory](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-21353-8) 
including the contributions of many authors (including myself).
Some chapters are quite introductory and could be of help for you.

As a general source, have a look at this page [Local Quantum Physics Crossroads: Bibliography](http://www.lqp2.org/bibliography). It contains several books on the subject of local quantum theories, including AQFT.

See also this page of the AQFT group of Hamburg [AQFTlecturenotes](http://unith.desy.de/research/aqft/lecture_notes/)
especially the last lecture notes by K.Fredenhagen. Klaus adopted those lecture notes in his courses before retiring.

Comment: can you suggest me some books to prepare myself for the mathematics for the purpose

Comment: Bratteli-Robinson's textbook for instance. But my suggestion is to prepare mathematics and physics simultaneously, the latter should be the guide for the former. The risk is to get lost in mathematics since this area is really huge.

Comment: It is with great sadness that I announce the passing of our distinguished
colleague Rudolf Haag. He died on January 5th 2016 at
the age of ninety-three. He worked to the very end on his more recent
prime topic, the foundations of quantum physics. His death is a tremendous
loss for our scientific community.